# Pass an object defined from a customed tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

To explain my situation, I have a `tableView` with custom `tableViewCell` and I have created a button in this customed cell. I want this button to add an object `box` which is already defined to an `NSMutableArray` and pass this array to `restoCardConfirmationViewController` in order to create a cart.

The problem is that when I try to display the `NSMutablearray` in `restoCardConfirmationViewController`, the result is nil. This is my code :

#### The boxTableViewCell :

```
#import "boxTableViewCell.h"
#import "RestoCardConfirmationViewController.h"
#import "RestauCardViewController.h"

@implementation boxTableViewCell {
NSMutableArray *_pickerPlace;
}
- (IBAction)select:(id)sender {
RestoCardConfirmationViewController *restauCardConfirmation = [[RestoCardConfirmationViewController alloc] init];
[restauCardConfirmation.boxesCommande addObject:_box];
NSLog(@"la box choisie est %@",_box);
self.select.enabled = NO;
if(!self.select.enabled){
    NSLog(@"button desabled");
}
}
```

#### The restoCardConfirmationViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface RestoCardConfirmationViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray *boxesCommande;
```

#### The restoCardConfirmationViewController.m :

```
#import "RestoCardConfirmationViewController.h"
#import "ChoisirDateViewController.h"

@interface RestoCardConfirmationViewController ()

@end

@implementation RestoCardConfirmationViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"The NSMutableArray in the other %@",self.boxesCommande);
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: where is the code that segues to restoCardConfirmationViewController? Please tell me where you are adding the navigation code!

Comment: I have the prepareForSegue method in the view that contain the tableView, but whe I can't add the object to the array in this ViewController from the tableViewCell

Comment: Are you sure this - (IBAction)select:(id)sender {} is called ?

Comment: @JennyJose Yes I called

Comment: My problem is when I try to add an object to the NSMutableArray in the other View Controler :     RestauCardViewController *restoCardVC = [[RestauCardViewController alloc] init];
    [restoCardVC.commande addObject:_box];

Comment: Yes this is happening because the data in RestauCardViewController is not retained till you perform segue. On every button click you alloc-init a new RestauCardViewController and not even once you are passing the array. Check my edited answer!

Comment: @JennyJose I should not instanciate the RestoCardViewController every time when I tap the button ?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is Delegation. Create a delegate that notifies every object added to RestoCardConfirmationViewController.

And the other simpler method is :

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.purchases count];
}
```

In the MainViewViewController, add button click event instead of  using it in tableview cell.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
     [cell.button addTarget:self 
                         action:@selector(select)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // ... 
}
```

This calls the following method, also implemented in MainViewController

```
    - (IBAction)select:(id)sender {

     int index = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;//it returns the indexPath

    [self.boxesArray addObject: self.purchases[index]];
    NSLog(@"la box choisie est %@",_box);


    self.select.enabled = NO;
    if(!self.select.enabled){
        NSLog(@"button desabled");
    }
    }
```

Now in prepareforSeque, pass the created array to RestoCardConfirmationViewController.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        RestoCardConfirmationViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        vc.boxesCommande = self.boxesArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Push To `ViewController` After addObject :

```
- (IBAction)select:(id)sender 
{
    RestoCardConfirmationViewController *restauCardConfirmation = [[RestoCardConfirmationViewController alloc] init];
    [restauCardConfirmation.boxesCommande addObject:_box];
    NSLog(@"la box choisie est %@",_box);
    self.select.enabled = NO;
    if(!self.select.enabled)
    {
        NSLog(@"button desabled");
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:restauCardConfirmation animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'boxTableViewCell'

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to initialize your boxesCommande array in your custom view controller.

Add the following lines to your RestoCardConfirmationViewController.m in the @implementation:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.boxesCommande = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I Always get that the NSMutableArray is null

Comment: Where do you push your RestoCardConfirmationViewController? You should implement a protocol for your cell so that it can pass the selected box to the controller which has the tableview. And then in that controller you can push the box into some array before pushing the RestoCardConfirmationViewController on the navigation stack

Comment: Yes, I have tried but I dont know how to implement this protocol. I have the prepareForSegue method in my RestoCardViewController

Comment: Add "NSLog(@"%@", restauCardConfirmation.boxesCommande)" after your NSLog "la box choisie est".. 
It shouldn't be nil if you added the init code I gave you. In any case I suggest you to document yourself on protocols. I wrote this a few months ago and have no time to post it here with a nice formatting, sorry: http://pastebin.com/JdEg1UDV